# Dump session to DB when restarting web server?

Tags: asp.net, session

How would one go about making sure the InProc session memory gets stored in a DB so it's possible to restart the web-server without losing sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Change SessionMode from "InProc" to "SQLServer" and insert the connectionstring to the sqlserver.

**Edit** after your comment:

> Using this mode ensures that session
>   state is preserved if the Web
>   application is restarted and also
>   makes session state available to
>   multiple Web servers in a Web farm.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind but I couldn't find out if this loses the current sessions?

Comment: Does this imply that the sessions won't get lost even if I switch from InProc _after_ the site's been online for a while?

Comment: If you are using InProc as SessionMode yes. With InProc it's simply not possible to keep the values - by design. For the desired behaviour you need to switch the SessionMode to SQLServer